# Tailwind-CSS config-file not "loading"

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I wanted to change the min-width of the screensize "md" in the config file but it's not loading it. The file is in the right place, written as in the docs and I even tried loading it manually, by writing it's directory in the tailwindcss watch-command

> My config-file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.export = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '924px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'xl': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

      '2xl': '1536px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your project’s breakpoints in the `theme.screens` section or `theme.extend.screens` of your `tailwind.config.js` file. Your screen configuration should be wrapped inside `screens` object

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.export = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'sm': '640px',
        // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

        'md': '924px',
        // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

        'lg': '1024px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

        'xl': '1280px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

        '2xl': '1536px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
      }
    },

  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir but it's still not working!

Comment: then I think the problem doesn't only come from that config file. You should provide more context of your project and for most important part, how you set up tailwindcss. Can you reveal your configuration?

Comment: I installed tailwind as in the docs described. Here is my folder displayed:
https://pastebin.com/XXjh5yVs

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Tailwind cli. Have you included /dist/output.css in your index.html?

Comment: First of all yes, I'm using Tailwind cli. And yes, I've included the output.css, outherwise the css wouldn't work.